# Get file to be read from another package

Tags: java, file, url, package, embedded-resource

I need to catch a file that is  package called `files`
I try use `getResourceAsStream` or

```
File file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("files/big.txt"));
```

However, is not working. This saying to convert for `URL`. If in this case I to use `URL`, I could do a downcasting, but is not working.

What I can do to solve that issue?

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one more slash "**/**" - If you are accessing from another package
As Commented Information, To Read the File use openStream() of URL

```
 URL url = getClass().getResource("/files/big.txt");
     try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String nameList;
            while ((nameList = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(nameList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I need to catch the file to read. In this case is a URL, so, not to going to works.

Comment: you can get from url.openStream() to file...see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file object you can call

```
fileUrl.getFile()
```

to get the file object